# Vue slots props inside blade template

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a Vue3 application that mounts on a blade/laravel. In one blade temlate, I have a Vue3 component (zest-dropzone) in which I insert a slot:

```
<template>
...

<slot name="hits" :button-label="buttonLabel" :files="files" :type="type" :state="state"></slot>
</template>

<script>
...
</script>
```

Inside the blade template, I have the following:

```
<zest-dropzone
    accepted-files=".psd,application/pdf,audio/*,image/*,video/*"
    button-label="{{ Lang::get('admin/button.edit') }}"
    categories="{{ json_encode($categories) }}"
    type="files">
    <template #hits="hitsProps">
      @{{ hitsProps.type }}
      <zest-dropzone-files-preview :hitsProps="hitsProps" :button-label="buttonLabel" :files="files" :type="type" :state="state"></zest-dropzone-files-preview>
    </template>
</zest-dropzone>
```

ZestDropzoneFilesPreview is another component which is registered globally and is technically rendered on the page, however the props are never coming no matter what I try.

Within the blade template, @{{ hitsProps.type }} renders correctly and the value type exists on hitsProps, however when I try to pass it in the next component, it doesn't come through and I get undefined inside ZestDropzoneFilesPreview.

Anyone knows how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, props were not passed accordingly (hitsProps -> hits-props).